# IQueryable filter on array of types

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Suppose an array of `Type` as criteria object which indicates the child types that must be shown.

Models:

```
public abstract class Shape { }

public class Circle : Shape { }

public class Rectangle : Shape { }
```

I've implemented an extension method which apply such query

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> OfTypes<TSource, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression, 
    params Type[] types)
{
    if (!types.Any())
    {
        return source;
    }

    Expression finalExpression = Expression.TypeIs(expression, types.First());

    foreach (var type in types.Skip(1))
    {
        finalExpression = Expression.OrElse(
            Expression.TypeIs(expression, type),
            finalExpression);
    }

    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
        finalExpression, 
        expression.Parameters);

    return source.Where(lambdaExpression);
}
```

Then I can use it like this

```
var types = new Type[] { typeof(Circle), typeof(Rectange) };
db.Shapres.OfTypes(s => s, types);
```

The generated expression is something like

```
e => e is Circle || e is Rectange
```

Exactly what I want but I get this error

> The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Even I used `AsExpandable()` method of [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) in the last line of the extension method:

```
return source.AsExpandable().Where(lambdaExpression);
```

But again the same error.

I've also tried [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) like this but again the same error

```
var finalExpression = PredicateBuilder.False<TSource>();

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var expressionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "it");
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
        Expression.TypeIs(expression, type), 
        expressionParameter);
    finalExpression.Or(lambdaExpression);
}
```

What is the problem?

How can I convert an `Expression` to an `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` in EF without problem?

Or how can I pass an `Expression` instance to the `Where` extension method?

Or how can I use `Expression.TypeIs` for EF?

Comment: `if (!types.Any())` could cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Steve - that is not my problem.

Comment: I know, just pointing it out.

Comment: I can help but notice that your example can be done without the Linq.Expression namespace.

Comment: Oh...I get it now...Not sure EF will work though. However, its pretty simple. You actually want to use `Expression finalExpression = Expression.TypeIs(expression.Body, types.First());`. Note the `.Body`. Took me hours to work that out using LinqPad to figure out how to do dynamic Linq. You may find you need to swap out every instance of the `ParameterExpression` as well. Plus, try it against an array before the database. The LinqToObjects compiler is more powerful than the LinqToEF compiler, and valid Linq might not compile on EF.

Comment: Are you just trying to create a linq extension `OfTypes`? That could be used like this: `db.Shapes.OfTypes(types)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter to the Lambda function, you are passing it the expression that was passed in, which is a lambda. Try creating the parameter inside of the extension method by removing the 'expression' argument as it's not needed.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> OfTypes<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        params Type[] types)
    {
        if (!types.Any())
        {
            return source;
        }

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "p");

        Expression finalExpression = Expression.TypeIs(param, types.First());

        foreach (var type in types.Skip(1))
        {
            finalExpression = Expression.OrElse(
                Expression.TypeIs(param, type),
                finalExpression);
        }

        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
            finalExpression, param);


        return source.Where(lambdaExpression);
    }
```

called like so:

```
var types = new Type[] { typeof(Circle), typeof(Rectangle) };
var test = context.Shapes.OfTypes(types);
```

Comment: It works correctly, but what if I wanted to use the expression to specify the property on which filter applys? For example `db.Shapes.OfTypes(s => s.SomeProperty, types);`. I mean is it impossible?